# Question about non zero-divisors

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is $\mathbb{Z}_7$ an example of a commutative ring with no zero divisors?

I came to this conclusion because $7$ is prime.

Can someone tell me if I am correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. For any prime $p$, the commutative ring $\mathbb{Z}_p$ has no zero divisors. In fact, it is even a field.